# System of ODE and its solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\mathbf{A}(t)=(a_{ij}(t))$ be a n by n matrix and $\mathbf{b}(t)$ be continuous on $|t-a|\leq T$. Prove that there exists $n+1$ solutions $\mathbf{x}^1, \cdots, \mathbf{x}^{n+1}$ of the non-homogeneous system

$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=$\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}(t)$

such that every solution $\mathbf{x}$ of this equation can be expressed as

$$\mathbf{x}(t)=\alpha_1\mathbf{x}^1(t)+\cdots+\alpha_{n+1}\mathbf{x}^{n+1}(t)$$

for some constants $\alpha_i$ with

$$\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n+1}=1$$. I am completely stuck on that, please helps. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one theorem that if $a_{ij}(t)$ is continuous on some interval $I$, then the solution space of the homogeneous equation $$\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{z}(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{z}(t)$$ is an $n$-dimension linear space, i.e., every solution of this equation can be expressed as $$\mathbf{z}(t)=c_1\mathbf{z}^1(t)+\cdots+c_n\mathbf{z}^n(t)$$ where $c_1, \cdots, c_n$ are constants.

Now for the non-homogeneous equation $$\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{x}(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)+\mathbf{b}(t)$$, suppose that $\mathbf{x}_0(t)$ is one of its solutions, then we can prove
\begin{split}
\mathbf{x}^1(t)&=\mathbf{x}_0(t)\\
\mathbf{x}^2(t)&=\mathbf{x}_0(t)+\mathbf{z}^1(t)\\
\mathbf{x}^3(t)&=\mathbf{x}_0(t)+\mathbf{z}^2(t)\\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{x}^{n+1}(t)&=\mathbf{x}_0(t)+\mathbf{z}^n(t)
\end{split}
are all the solutions of the inhomogeneous equation. And they are linearly independent and can express any solution $\mathbf{x}(t)$ of this equation, i.e., $$\mathbf{x}(t)=\alpha_1\mathbf{x}^1(t)+\cdots+\alpha_{n+1}\mathbf{x}^{n+1}(t)$$ If we put this formula above into the equation based on $\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{x}_0(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}_0(t)+\mathbf{b}(t)$ and $\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{z}^i(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{z}^i(t)$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$, then it's easy to find that $$\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_{n+1}=1$$. And if the dimension of the solution space of the non-homogeneous is bigger than $n+1$, we can conclude that the dimension of the homogeneous equation is bigger than $n$, which is impossible.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! But I have one more question, namely that we knew the dimension of the solution space is $n$, but then we also proved that $\mathbf{x}^1, \cdots, \mathbf{x}^{n+1}$ are linearly independent, isn't that a contradiction? @Kevin Yang

Comment: I mean the dimension of the solution space of the homogeneous system is $n$, not the non-homogeneous system, whose solution space is $(n+1)$-dimension.

Comment: I see, thank you so much!